# Adding a class in php if one field is displayed

Tags: php, wordpress, class, plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working with the ACF plugin in Wordpress, and on the page displaying all my articles, I would like to style them depending on their categories (which are set with the ACF plugin). So basically the idea is to say : if this article is displaying the "movies" category, then give it the class "blue".

I've been trying a few things but none of them work :( Since I'm not a PHP pro, I was wondering if anyone out there could help me out with the right syntax ?

This is how I conditionnaly display a field :

```
     <?php if ( get_field('site_web') ): ?> 
    <span class="niveau">Site Web : 
<a href="<?php the_field('site_web'); ?>" target="_blank"><span class="white">
    <?php echo the_field('site_web') ?></span></a></span><br />
                                      <?php endif; ?>
```

So if the field `site_web` exists, give it the class `red`

Thanks for the answers !

_________ EDIT ____________

Jeez okay I've just realized how what I just posted has no sense.
The actual problem (and I should've mentionned that straight away) is that if the field is displayed, it means it's displaying three different possibilities.
In the ACF plugin I've created a field displaying levels : easy, hard, very hard.

So I'd like to display a class depending on the level it's displaying !

Thanks ever so much for being so reactive, and helping me out. And sorry for not being very clear...

Comment: Being as the whole code section is contained within `<?php if ( get_field('site_web') ): ?>` then surely you can justb change the css class: `<span class="red">`

Answer (score 0):

Never coded something for Wordpress, but maybe something like that

```
$cssClass = (isset(get_field('site_web')) ? "red" : "";
echo '<span class="'.$cssClass .'">Site Web</span>';
```

Comment: you have a small typo, `$class` should be `$cssClass`

Comment: Ok I wanted to rewrite this question but I edited it yesterday because I didn't ask properly what I was looking for. Is there someone out there with answers to the new question ? Sorry for posting to quickly...